# I have a list of Object. I want to print all object except one object which firstName is "Avijit". How can i do it with stream?

Tags: stream

Here the code

```
import java.util.List;


public class StreamDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<User> name = new ArrayList<>();
        name.add(new User(1,"Avijit","Barua","aavi1234"));
        name.add(new User(2,"Mezanul","Haque","mezan1234"));
        name.add(new User(3,"Subrata","Nath","subrata1234"));
        name.add(new User(4,"Raman","Karmakar","raman1234"));
        name.add(new User(5,"Mowdud","Ahmed","mowdud1234"));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems i got an answer.

```
name.stream()
    .filter(p -> p.getFirstName()!="Avijit")
    .forEach(p -> System.out.println(p));
```